# Returning an iterator type defined in another crate

Tags: rust

I'm trying to forward an iterator through a function to give constructing the iterator a more friendly interface.

This was an attempt that didn't quite work

```
pub fn rep_cartesian_product<'a, T>(iter: T, n: i32)-> itertools::MultiProduct<T> 
where T: Iterator + Clone {
    (0..n).map(|_| iter).multi_cartesian_product()
}
```

One of the errors I get is:

"The trait `std::clone::Clone` is not implemented for `<T as std::iter::Iterator>::Item`". But I'm not sure why this is the case since I put `+ Clone` in the where clause.

A prior attempt was

```
pub fn rep_cartesian_product<'a, T>(iter: T, n: i32)-> impl Iterator<Item = Vec<T>>
where T : Iterator {
    (0..n).map(|_| iter).multi_cartesian_product()
}
```

type mismatch resolving `<itertools::MultiProduct<T> as std::iter::Iterator>::Item == std::vec::Vec<T>` which is why I tried the previous shared attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You requested that the iterator be `Clone`, but you additionally need to request that the items it produces are themselves `Clone` with a trait bound like `T::Item: Clone`.

Additionally, `(0..n).map(|_| iter)` doesn't compile because `map()` expects a closure it can call multiple times, and returning `iter` makes the closure callable only once. You can fix that by switching to `.map(|_| iter.clone())` - or by using `std::iter::repeat()` instead.

Here is a version that compiles:

```
pub fn rep_cartesian_product<T>(iter: T, n: usize) -> itertools::MultiProduct<T>
where
    T: Iterator + Clone,
    T::Item: Clone,
{
    std::iter::repeat(iter).take(n).multi_cartesian_product()
}
```

Note that you can also return `impl Iterator<Item = Vec<T::Item>>`, which has the advantage of hiding the implementation of the iterator.